# Powerpoint 2016 VBA Pictures

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I'm a little new to all this got myself a little in over my head with a project and was wondering if i could get a little guidance.

I'll set the scene for you. I have a power point it has 3 layers of pictures, they are all cards. The back layer is my place holders just random cards of suit and value. Second layer is a layer of Ace's and the final layer is the card backs.
i have 20 sets of these 3 images i have set a nice little spin transition so you click the trigger of the card back they spin and they ace will show up everytime because its before the placeholder.

The idea is i have 1 macro which is my reset and it would push them all to the back using ZOrder msoSendToBack.

A second macro which would then random bring 3 of the aces forward 3 times so they are inline with the layer then need to be to be shown first. Now the problems i face is the VBA code.

```
Sub Reset()
     ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("Picture29").Select
     ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.ZOrder msoSendToBack
End Sub
```

This is the code i have found via general look up.

I would appreciate any guidance or advice, i realise i may be doing this the harder way. I'm only a software engineering student so im newish to this. But im stronger with C# or Java. But honestly anything to would appreicated.

Answer (score 0):

First, avoid selecting ANYTHING unless it's totally unavoidable. 
This will have the same effect:

```
Sub Reset()
     With ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("Picture29")
        .ZOrder msoSendToBack
     End With
End Sub
```

Since you have to deal with more than one shape, I'd be inclined to use Tags.
For example, select a shape, then run this:

Sub BackLayer()
   With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
      .Tags.Add "Layer", "Back"
   End With
End Sub

Do this for each of your back layer items, then identify your other layer shapes similarly.  Then in use, [aircode alert!]

```
Sub Reset()
   Dim oSh as Shape
   For Each oSh in ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1)
      If oSh.Tags("Layer") = "Back" Then
         oSh.Zorder msoSendToBack
      End If
      ' Add further IF tests to identify other layers
      ' and deal with them appropriately
   Next
End Sub
```